# Postgres funnel analysis (time spent)

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
id  visited_time                        page visitor_id 
1   2019-04-29T10:44:53.847014+02:00    1   1
2   2019-04-29T10:46:53.174894+02:00    1   3
3   2019-04-29T10:49:44.000390+02:00    2   1
18  2019-04-29T10:52:46.574140+02:00    2   3
19  2019-04-29T10:52:58.158146+02:00    3   1
20  2019-04-29T10:53:27.402038+02:00    1   9
25  2019-04-29T10:55:18.275441+02:00    2   9
54  2019-04-29T11:10:01.818343+02:00    1   13
72  2019-04-29T11:40:28.056813+02:00    2   13
```

A visitor will also be going from page 1 to 2 to 3 and so forth (but can dropout along the way). I want to find the average time spent on each page. Logically this is the difference between the a unique visitor_id visited page 1 and then page 2 etc.

Is there a smart way to do this in postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```sql
SELECT
    page,
    avg(visited_time_next - visited_time)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            page,
            visited_time,
            -- the time of the next page view by a certain visitor...
            lead(visited_time) OVER (PARTITION BY visitor_id ORDER BY visited_time) AS visited_time_next
        FROM visits_so_56097366
    ) AS tmp
GROUP BY page
ORDER BY page;
```

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=e64dd8862350b9357d9a4384937868c9

Please also make sure that you have an index over `visitor_id` and `visited_time`, otherwise you'll end up with very expensive sorts for larger number of intermediate rows: